# Save All Google Form Responses into single PDF

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I need to create a pdf so that all the responses got in google form should be present in that pdf.

**What I did**

I clicked on response tab of google-form then clicked on print all responses which generated pdf for all responses but I don't like the format of that pdf.

Then I used Document studio add-on for google spreadsheet (which contains the responses for each user) but it generates pdf for each user rather than all responses in single pdf.

**What I need**

Is there a way that creates pdf for all responses in a custom format just like Document Studio?

Comment: Maybe you can merge the user PDFs using another utility program.

Comment: @DimuDesigns Do you know a utility program that can help me to convert all responses with custom pdf format?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can try to write your own solution with Google Apps Script but if you have a large number of responses you're going to run into time-out issues.

Comment: I am the developer of the Document Studio addon. The latest version does offer you an option to merge all form data from the Google Sheet in a single PDF file. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGipS.png

Comment: @AmitAgarwal I have tried to contact you but didn't get response from you, because the option doesn't work in document studio.

Comment: It only merges pdf into single file but I need only responses into single pdf not sum  up all pdfs into single pdf.

Comment: Looks like you want something very customized. You'll probably have to develop this yourself (or hire someone to do it).

Comment: @HenriqueG.Abreu I will develop it myself, could you please share a link which can help/guide me to create pdf using app-script.